# RegExp equivalent of an actual regex string

Tags: javascript, regex

Please what is the RegExp equivalent of `/^STRINGA/i` in javascript?
For example, `new RegExp('country', 'i')` will give `/country/i`, but i do not know how to achieve the aforementioned regex.

Comment: My current workaround is to cacatenate `^` to the string before passing it to the regex, but there should be a proper way of going about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as first I want to say in javascript we can write regex 2 ways

1. literal likes **/pattern/modifiers**  using slashes **/**
2. constructor likes **new RegExp("pattern", "modifiers")** using constructor function

regex has several special characters if a pattern has a special character you can scaping with the use of backslash **\ this backslash also I used inside of StackOverflow editor 2-time then it showed**  it scaping any special character.

```js
const pattern = /\/\^STRINGA\/i/;
const string = '/^STRINGA/i';
console.log(string.match(pattern));
```

**Note:** **/**  **/** first and last slashes used to making the regex pattern, and all **\** backslash used for scaping the special character

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape special characters. For example, using the `RegExp` constructor, you can do this:

```js
const ex = new RegExp('\\/\\^STRINGA\\/i');
console.log('/^STRINGA/i'.match(ex));
```

And using an expression, you can do this:

```js
const ex = /\/\^STRINGA\/i/;
console.log('/^STRINGA/i'.match(ex));
```